# create a tar of a folder with numeric value having specific subfolder

Tags: grep, find, tar

I have a situation where I am dumping my webcontent folder to buildNumber folder each time building.
eg. Myproject/**12345/webcontent**
Now obviously, this buildNumber will keep on changing.

How can I make a tar of this folder? I need a generic solution script so that I dont have to change my deploy script each time after build.

PS: webcontent folder name is static and can be used for grep or find.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will back up the highest numbered directory and include the revision number in the backup's name:

```
#!/bin/bash

BuildNum=`ls Myproject/ | sort | tail -1`
tar -zcf backup-${BuildNum}.tgz Myproject/${BuildNum}/webcontent
```

Comment: Thanks Robert! I modified it to suit my needs:
BuildNum=`ls | grep -E '[0-9]{5}'`
tar -cvf backup-${BuildNum}.tar ./${BuildNum}